# Combining data from 2 mongoDB collections into 1 document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want to filter 2 collections and return one document.

I have 2 MongoDB collections modelled as such

**Analytics_Region**

```
    _id:5ecf3445365eca3e58ff57c0,
    type:"city"
    name:"Toronto"
    CSD:"3520005"
    CSDTYPE:"C"
    PR:"35"
    PRNAME:"Ontario"
    geometry:Object
    country:"CAN"
    updatedAt:2021-04-23T18:25:50.774+00:00
    province:"ON"
```

**Analytics_Region_Custom**

```
    _id:5ecbe871d8ab4ab6845c5142
    geometry:Object
    name:"henry12"
    user:5cbdd019b9d9170007d15990
    __v:0
```

I want to output a single collection in **alphabetical order by name**,

```
    {
       _id: 5ecbe871d8ab4ab6845c5142,
       name: "henry12",
       type: "custom",
       province: null
    
    },
    {
        _id:5ecf3445365eca3e58ff57c0,
        name:"Toronto"
        type:"city"
        province:"ON",
    }
```

Things to note: In the output, we have added a type of "custom" for every document in Analytics_Region_custom. We also add a province of "null" for every document.

So far I looked into `$lookup` (to fetch results from another collection) but it does not seem to work for my needs since it adds an array onto every document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unionWith` to perform union of both collections
- `$project` to project only fields that you want
- `sort` to sort by **name** field

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $unionWith: "inventory"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      province: { $cond: { if: "$province",  then: "$province", else: null } },
      type: { $cond: { if: "$type", then: "$type", else: "custom" } }
    }
  },
  { 
    $sort: { name: 1 }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oIOSTkJnbh6)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$unionWith`
Documents will be added to the pipeline(no check for duplicates), and from those documents we will project the fields

- if type is missing  => custom
- if province missing => null

*if those 2 have any false value, like `false/0/null` the old value is kept (new value only if field is missing)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ajHSJn_JFRI)

```js
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "coll2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$name",
      "type": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$ne": [
              {
                "$type": "$type"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          "$type",
          "custom"
        ]
      },
      "province": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$ne": [
              {
                "$type": "$province"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          "$province",
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "name": 1      
    }
  }
])
```